# How to Add column Value to a Set Variable in Mysql in an Update Statement?

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
update my_table set credits_total = credits_total + 1 where id = 4;
```

But this doesn't:

```
SET @add_credits = 1;
update my_table set credits_total = credits_total + @add_credits where id = 4;
```

It's giving me a 'column credits_total cannot be null' error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using? And what is the initial value of credits_total?

Comment: Should work please add table definition and sample data.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpddLaQyFuqV472xJiGLya/0